# Class variable cannot be found even when defined

Tags: python, pygame

I am  having a problem with my code, in that as I try and call a class variable( in my case UPIC1), and define it as something else, an error is returned saying that ' NameError: name 'UPIC1' is not defined '. 
My code is essentially defining classes that, when called, load the UPIC images, crop them and display them to the screen. If this is formatted incorrectly, them I am sorry as this is my first time posting to stack overflow

Here is the code

```
import pygame
import sys
black = (0,0,0)
yellow = (255,242,0)
light_yellow = (255,251,270) 
red = (237,28,36)
light_red =(243,91,99)
backgroundblue = (130,255,252)
white = (255, 64, 64)
#defines scale of pictures in px
PICScale = 300
defines resolution
w = 1280
h = 720
pygame.init()

class Question:


    def __init__(self,userinput, UPIC1, UPIC2, UPIC3):
        self.userinput=userinput
        self.UPIC1=UPIC1
        self.UPIC2=UPIC2
        self.UPIC3=UPIC3


q1 = Question('alpha', pygame.image.load('img1a.png'), pygame.image.load('img1b.png'), 'n/a')

q2 = Question('beta', pygame.image.load('img2a.png'), pygame.image.load('img2b.png'), 'n/a')

q3 = Question('gamma', pygame.image.load('img3a.png'), pygame.image.load('img3b.png'), 'n/a')

q4 = Question('brownian', pygame.image.load('img4a.png'), pygame.image.load('img4b.png'), 'n/a')

q5 = Question('electromagnet', pygame.image.load('img5a.png'), pygame.image.load('img5b.png'), 'n/a')

q6 = Question('quark', pygame.image.load('img6a.png'), pygame.image.load('img6b.png'), 'n/a')

q7 = Question('inertia', pygame.image.load('img7a.png'), pygame.image.load('img7b.png'), pygame.image.load('img7c.png'))

q8 = Question('ion', pygame.image.load('img8a.png'), pygame.image.load('img8b.png'), 'n/a')

q9 = Question('matter', pygame.image.load('img9a.png'), pygame.image.load('img9b.png'), 'n/a')

q10 = Question('nuclear', pygame.image.load('img10a.png'), pygame.image.load('img10b.png'), 'n/a')

q11= Question('displacement', pygame.image.load('img11a.png'), pygame.image.load('img11b.png'), 'n/a')

q12 = Question('pendulum', pygame.image.load('img12a.png'), pygame.image.load('img12b.png'),pygame.image.load('img12c.png'))

q13 = Question('resistance', pygame.image.load('img13a.png'), pygame.image.load('img13b.png'),'n/a')

q14 = Question('momentum', pygame.image.load('img14a.png'), pygame.image.load('img14b.png'),pygame.image.load('img14c.png'))

q15 = Question('ampere', pygame.image.load('img15a.png'), pygame.image.load('img15b.png'), 'n/a')

q1.UPIC1 = UPIC1

PIC1 = pygame.transform.scale(UPIC1, (PICScale,PICScale))


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
screen.fill((backgroundblue))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((backgroundblue))
    screen.blit(PIC1,(w/2-(3/2*PICScale),0))
    pygame.display.flip()`enter code here`
```

Comment: `q1.UPIC1 = UPIC1` requires a *global name* `UPIC1` to be defined. The same applies for the `UPIC1` use in the next line.

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you set a class attribute. You do set an *instance attribute* in the `Question.__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a global variable anywhere in your code, so you are trying to give the class a value that doesn't exist yet. your code should add a line saying

```
UPIC1 = "Value"
```

before the line

```
q1.UPIC1 = UPIC1
```